# Confusion of file structure after generating Tag of code

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm relatively new to SVN but not a complete beginner. I recently tried to restructure my local copy for a project I'm working on. I then tried to create a tag of my project, and now I'm confused as my file locations/naming don't line up when comparing my up-to-date local copy versus what I see in Repo Browser.

**File "Structure":**

My root folder is called Reliability, both in the Repo and on my local. I have Reliability/Trunk, .../Branch, ../Tags in the Repo- but until recently have always just kept everything in Trunk and did Updates/Commits there.

In "Trunk" I had a folder "Instrument Drivers" which contained subfolders for various instrument drivers I've developed. I decided to SVNmove that folder out of trunk, to the top-level root folder and then branch the project back into trunk so that I could have a development copy in Trunk and a "ready to use copy" in the top-level. I did this as I felt it was the more correct way of using SVN. So in short, I moved:

/Reliability/trunk/Instrument Drivers/Source/AgilentDAQ

to

/Reliability/Instrument Drivers/Source/AgilentDAQ

That worked fine. Next I wanted to create a "tag" of one of my current Instrument Drivers (.../AgilentDAQ) for 1.0 and place in the /Reliability/Tags folder as /Reliability/Tags/AgilentDAQ-1.0

It seemed to work but then I started getting all of these conflicts and alerts about duplicate files and working directory issues (I may have accidentally set my working copy to Tags). I spent a lot of time trying to clean it up before the holiday break and am not 100% sure what changes I made (I've reviewed the log and there's a lot to digest). Point is, what I see now is confusing me and I don't know if its because I really messed something up or just that this is how Tags work.

Why does my local repository and the repo-browser show different structure?

Everything looks fine in RepoBroswer, but I have a new folder in my local that looks to be the tag. Yet it exists on the same file-level as the source version, but under a new subfolder with the same name as my root. Does SVN physically store the Tag files in the main repository it was tagged from?

[Here's pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzu7q.jpg), but here's a summary of what I currently am seeing.

In RepoBrowser I see what I expect:
/Reliability/Instrument Drivers/Source/AgilentDAQ (*expected*)
/Reliability/Tags/AgilentDAQ-1.0 (*expected*)

Local Disk, I'm confused:
C:/Reliability/Instrument Drivers/Source/AgilentDAQ (*expected*)
C:/Reliability/Instrument Drivers/Source/Reliability/AgilentDAQ-1.0 (*It's a duplicate of AgilentDAQ above which I expect since it's a tag, but why is it physically on my disk under Instrument Drivers folder and why is it nested under another subfolder called "Reliability" which is my root directory*)

Help is much appreciated, trying to finally force myself to properly utilize SVN and be a better developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so to begin things off, I just want you to know that the moment you moved everything from underneath trunk, you've broken the "traditional" paradigm for subversion repositories.

So you have a repository called **Reliability** I assume. The default directory structure should be (and was):

```
Reliability
|_branches
|_tags
|_trunk
    |_Instrument Drivers
```

First, let me explain the purpose of the `branches`, `tags`, and `trunk` directories.

**branches** - This folder is typically designated as the directory for developers to make bug fixes, add new features, etc. to whatever feature you're working on. You essentially make copies of the `trunk`, make whatever changes you need to make, and once they're tested and working, you merge those changes back to the `trunk`.

**tags** - This directory is typically meant for stable versions, or a snapshot, of the repository. For example, let's say whatever application you're working on has officially been released as version 1.0. At the time of release, developers will typically take a "snapshot" of the repository and tag the `trunk` underneath this directory. You will ideally see something like

```
Reliability
|_ tags
    |__ 1.0
```

Where **1.0** will be a copy of the state/revision of the `trunk`. One important thing to note is that tags are typically **never** to be modified. They're simply used as reference points during development. For example, if something breaks in between versions and you need to go back to verify something works, you can use this checkout string as a reset point.

**trunk** - The trunk is the active working development branch of your repository. It's meant to be where all of the developer activity begins and ends. Whenever you've finished working on your features in a branch, you merge them back into the trunk. You make releases from your trunk. When you have a new task you'll branch *from* the trunk. (Yes, you can make changes directly to the trunk but for lots of developers working on the same repository, conflicts are bound to arise).

I can go into more detail about this structure if you'd like, feel free to ask if you have any additional questions but that's the general idea.

Now for your issues:

1. For future reference, don't SVN Move items to the root of any
   repository.
2. I'm not exactly sure what you did, but it looks like you did an
   SVN Checkout of Reliability *inside* the Instrument Drivers folder
   (I can tell because there's another .svn folder underneath
   Reliability/Instrument Drivers/Reliability).
3. This is more of a nitpick, but as a developer you should know
   this and keep it in mind. On Windows, capitalization doesn't matter,
   but on Unix/Linux it will matter. Make sure you're using consistent
   capitalization. So whenever you're trying to branch to a tag/branch
   make sure you're using the correct casing.
4. You *typically* want to tag the entirety of the trunk, but if you have an immediate desire to tag just the AgilentDAQ directory, you can simply right click on the AgilentDAQ directory (inside of the **trunk**) > **TortoiseSVN** > **Branch/Tag...** and inside of the field **To path**: you want to point it at `tags/AgilentDAQ-1.0`.

So as of right now, your repo and working copy is in kind of a mess, but it can be recovered (hence why you're using a versioning system ;) ). Hopefully this can help guide you to sorting out your repo.

Comment: Ok, this all makes sense. 

My goal was to have a single local folder...

C:/Reliability/Instrument Drivers 

that I could easily switch the working copy to/from Trunk and Branches. Or in other words, I wanted to abstract my local file structure from which repository WD I was in.

So it makes sense after reading your post that I shouldn't have SVNmoved the repository, and instead recreated the file structure on my local (ie remove the "trunk" folder and move everything up). Looks like I have some cleaning up to do.

Also thanks for taking the time to go into detail, its a huge help!